# flat, unselectable, uneditable data_grid_view (without header) in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to display records in data-grid-view. But i do not need column and row header.

I also do not need interactive type of DGV. like editing, changing ROW/COLUMN size etc.
The DGV should simply look like a picture(not like table in excel).

How can it be done?

Comment: If you don't need any of that, why do you need a data grid view in the first place? Also, include a screenshot of you want it to look, cause right now "it's unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 0):

use listview control, 
set view to details

[link to listview description on msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx)